# cant import compass to symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm trying to implement some small project into symfony2.5, 
when I have added the the configurations of the compass to my config file and installed all the needed packages (ruby,sass,compass) though when I'm trying to assetic:dump the css I get the following

```
Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                         
  Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.                                                                                                                               
         Load path: /path/to/project/CoreBundle/Resources/public/css                                                                                                   
          on line 6 of /tmp/assetic_sassE4kCr8
```

if I remove the @import "compass"; I still get the same problem with the @import "compass/css3"; AND the @import "compass/utilities/sprites";

in my config.yml I get the assetic set like the following:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ FundCoreBundle ]
    filters:
        scss:
            bin: "/usr/local/bin/sass"
        compass:
            bin: "/usr/local/bin/compass"
```

my css creation is as the following:

```
{% stylesheets
        '@FundCoreBundle/Resources/public/css/style.scss'
        filter='compass'
        output='css/*.css'

        %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

and my scss file is as the following

```
/* Compass utilities*/
// Use one CSS3 mixin instead of multiple vendor prefixes.
// @import "compass/support";
// @import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass";
// See http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
// Helps set up a vertical rhythm.
// @import "compass/typography/vertical_rhythm";

// Sass utilities
@import "helpers/variables";
@import "helpers/mixins";

// Vendors and external stylesheets
// @import "vendors/mmenu/jquery.mmenu";
@import "vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap";

// Base stuff
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/normalize";
@import "base/main";
```

what is the right way to import compass +ccs3 + sprites to the symfony project?